# Подсчитать количество массивов в многомерном массиве

Tags: php

Как подсчитать количество массивов в многомерном массиве?

```
$myArray = array(
  array( <var>value1</var>, <var>value2</var>, <var>value3</var> ), //массив1
  array( <var>value4</var>, <var>value5</var>, <var>value6</var> ), //массив2
  array( <var>value7</var>, <var>value8</var>, <var>value9</var> )  //массив3
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `count()`:

```
 $count = count($myArray);
```

Comment: Это фигня. Оно выводит число 4, хотя у меня таких массивов далеко не 4. И даже не 10.

Comment: Не нужно отправлять людей в гугл. Это поисковики сюда должны вести (и ведут), а не наоборот.

Comment: JamesJGoodwin, можете привести пример массива, где `count()` работает неправильно? Например: http://ideone.com/XDGzDV

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin вам надо количество массивов рекурсивно узнать? Вы можете в таком случае обойти массив рекурсивным иттератором, см. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array